# Unable to override Admin Review Grid Block

Tags: adminhtml, overrides

I want to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid but not able to do that. Following is my config file

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wibsoft_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Wibsoft_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_grid>Wibsoft_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid</review_grid>
                 </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: what is the exact problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Please also post the class you've written

Answer (score 0):

Override class **NameSpace_moduleName_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid** from your created custom module. Add the below code into your **config.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Wibsoft>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Wibsoft>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <wibsoft>
        <class>Custom_Wibsoft_Block</class>
      </wibsoft>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_grid>Custom_Wibsoft_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid</review_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding the same.

Comment: I noticed that someone have provided negative marking for my reply. May I know the reason for the same?

Comment: Your reply is basically a copy and paste of the original question with some node name changes.

Comment: @Smartie, Have you checked difference between both codes? Namespace is not called in the original question, through which successful results is not possible. Please try both codes by "COPY-PASTING" into your local module config xml file.